# Variable cannot be accesed or is not saved in Gitlab ci job

Tags: docker, shell, gitlab

I am trying to get the directories that contain Dockerfile files in Gitlab CI, and then do some operations (that I have omitted) with those directories.

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have this script that works correctly

```
script:
    - RESPONSE=$(find . -type f -name Dockerfile)
    - |
      if [ -z "$RESPONSE" ]; then
        echo No Dockerfiles found;
        exit 1;
      else
        echo Found Dockerfiles;
        echo $RESPONSE
      fi
```

Then, I have a template with exactly the same script:

```
script:
    - cd $BUILDIR && pwd && ls
    - RESPONSE=$(find . -type f -name Dockerfile | sed "s|^\./||")
    - echo $RESPONSE
    - |
      if [ -z "$RESPONSE" ]; then
        echo No Dockerfiles found;
        echo $RESPONSE;
      else
        echo Found Dockerfiles;
        RESPONSE=$(echo $RESPONSE | xargs -n 1 dirname);
      fi
```

The problem is that, when executed, I get the following:

```
$ RESPONSE=$(find . -type f -name Dockerfile | sed "s|^\./||")
$ echo
$ if [ -z "" ]; then # collapsed multi-line command
No Dockerfiles found
```

As you can see `$RESPONSE` is not recognized or is not declared or I don't know, the `echo $RESPONSE` command does not work, as the executed command is `echo`, and then, when checking if the `$RESPONSE` array is empty, the same happens.

Is this because this happens in a template? I have tried to escape the dollar sign, use curly braces, but nothing works. There ARE Dockerfile files in the directories, so the `find` command should work.

The whole job:

```
delayed-build-files-cleaning:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    GIT_CLONE_PATH: ${BUILDIR}
  script:
    - cd $BUILDIR && pwd && ls
    - RESPONSE=$(find . -type f -name Dockerfile | sed "s|^\./||")
    - echo $RESPONSE
    - |
      if [ -z "$RESPONSE" ]; then
        echo No Dockerfiles found;
        echo $RESPONSE;
      else
        echo Found Dockerfiles;
        RESPONSE=$(echo $RESPONSE | xargs -n 1 dirname);
        for i in "${RESPONSE[@]}"
        do
          cd ${i};
          !reference [.docker-tag-script, script];
          echo "Removing last docker image build";
          docker rmi $NEXUS_DOCKER_REGISTRY/${DOCKER_TARGET_IMAGE};
          cd .. 
        done
      fi
    - find . -delete
  when: delayed
  start_in: 120 minutes
  tags:
    - dev
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `variable: RESPONSE: ""` anywhere in your gitlab-ci? Please post the whole job. Please try changing `REPONSE` to for example `response` - prefer using lower case variables for script local variables.

Comment: @KamilCuk no, the gitlab-ci uses `RESPONSE` but does not declare it an empty string. This job is executed in delay to clean the images and the builds, so no other script is running at the same time.

Comment: `"${RESPONSE[@]}"` REPONSE is not an array. Please try with differnt variable name. Do not use upper case varibales for local variables.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have tried renaming it, lowercase, declaring it by exporting the variable, none of them are working.

Comment: Have you verified the output of the command in `$(...)`? Maybe before assigning `RESPONSE` variable, try adding a step: `- find . -type f -name Dockerfile | sed "s|^\./||"`

Comment: where is the `BUILDIR` variable defined? If you want to use the predefined variable, it's `CI_BUILDS_DIR` Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: @Arty-chan It is defined in the gitlab ci main file. It works correctly and the routes are ok. The problem comes when trying to access de variable

Comment: @keypress yes. The find command works correctly, the problem is when declaring the variable. I have tried to skip declaring it and using only inline commands, but for the for loop, when doin `for i in (pipe)` and then trying to acces $i, it does not work, and the echo command in the output is just `echo`. It seems like I cant declare any variable.

Comment: Can you provide more of the job output? What happens after the `ls`? Does it list the Dockerfile?

Comment: yes, it lists all folders. Then I tried `ls` in one of the folders and the Dockerfile is there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In the gitlab ci file, the template is used among envsubst with no specified variables, so ALL variables declared inside the template will 'disappear'.

Before fix

`(export BUILDIR='pwd'; export FOLDER=%; envsubst < .gitlab-ci-clean-build-files-template.yml ...`

After fix

`(export BUILDIR='pwd'; export FOLDER=%; envsubst \$BUILDIR,\$FOLDER < .gitlab-ci-clean-build-files-template.yml ...`